# How to add rows to a column based on values in other column

Tags: r, database, addition

I have a big DF.
First column is named "ID", besides I have column "days". 
I have more than 4000 different values in ID that repeat themselves and in column "days" I have values from -60 to 60. My problem is that not all ID values have all values from -60 to 60 in "days", and I need that any ID value has the entire range in "days" (-60 to 60).

```
DF <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3...4000), days=c(-60,-59,-58....60),...)
```

I need to fill the column "days" with the lacking values for each "ID" value.

Sorry if I am not clear enough.

Thank you very much!

This is an example of my DF

```
Data.frame':    8 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ Farm      : Factor w/ 7 levels "Abel","Bollant",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 $ ID        : int  10000 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000
 $ Date      : Factor w/ 395 levels "1/1/2015","1/10/2015",..: 63 89 85 66 64 77 65 36
 $ Rum       : int  622 619 706 455 563 594 589 681
 $ Act       : int  438 484 466 449 471 546 449 424
 $ FDAT      : Factor w/ 304 levels "1/1/2015","1/10/2015",..: 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 46
 $ daystocalv: int  -10 -15 -12 -21 -19 -31 -20 9
 $ Prepartum : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can show others your effort when you take the time to create a small example of your problem. We stress that for three reasons, 1) it helps others understand your problem, 2) it allows everyone to try the code themselves to work out a solution, and 3) many times you will find your answer while creating the example itself.

Example:

```
df <- data.frame(x=rep(LETTERS[1:3], c(2,3,5)), y=c(-2,0,-1,0,1, -2,-1,0,1,2), stringsAsFactors=F)
df
#    x  y
# 1  A -2
# 2  A  0
# 3  B -1
# 4  B  0
# 5  B  1
# 6  C -2
# 7  C -1
# 8  C  0
# 9  C  1
# 10 C  2
```

This example takes three ids with a range from -2 to 2. ID "C" is complete but the others do not have all of the values. It only took 20 seconds to create but it helps tremendously to visualize the problem.

Solution:

`complete` works by looking at the groups and extending to fill in any missing values:

```
library(tidyr)
complete(df, x, y)
# Source: local data frame [15 x 2]
# 
#        x     y
#    (chr) (dbl)
# 1      A    -2
# 2      A    -1
# 3      A     0
# 4      A     1
# 5      A     2
# 6      B    -2
# 7      B    -1
# 8      B     0
# 9      B     1
# 10     B     2
# 11     C    -2
# 12     C    -1
# 13     C     0
# 14     C     1
# 15     C     2
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am trying to use *expand* (tiplyr). expand(df,nesting(df$x),df$y). Then now I have all days for every ID (being x=ID, y=days). I created a vector and now I am tying to merge the original df with the vector, but I run over memory, so I cant. My idea is to expand (nesting) all the variables of the df instead merging. How can I nest all variables of df?

Comment: Are you confusing `dplyr` and `tidyr`? There is no package or function called `tiplyr` that I know of

Comment: sorry, it is tidyr

Comment: You have not taken my advice. Please take 5 minutes to create a small example of your data so that you will not have to explain everything in words. Do you understand why I am asking for you to give an example?

Comment: Try this, enter `dput(head(df))` and post the result in your question.

Comment: Impossible, it is too big. My DF has more than 100 columns and 400000 rows.

Comment: You can do `dput(df[1:8, 1:8])`

Comment: I did: str(DCDF6060d0pre30[1:8, 1:8]). Result: 'data.frame': 8 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ Farm      : Factor w/ 7 levels "Abel","Bollant",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 $ ID        : int  10000 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000
 $ Date      : Factor w/ 395 levels "1/1/2015","1/10/2015",..: 63 89 85 66 64 77 65 36
 $ Rum       : int  622 619 706 455 563 594 589 681
 $ Act       : int  438 484 466 449 471 546 449 424
 $ FDAT      : Factor w/ 304 levels "1/1/2015","1/10/2015",..: 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 46
 $ daystocalv: int  -10 -15 -12 -21 -19 -31 -20 9
 $ Prepartum : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0

Comment: I did not say `str`. Please if you will just listen you can solve your problem. Add the output of `dput(df[1:8, 1:8])` TO YOUR QUESTION. not in the comments

Comment: Sorry but the result I obtain is not compatible for being posted. Too big.

Comment: It is printing all factors. Run this and post the output. `df1=df[1:8,1:8];df1[]=lapply(df1,function(x)if(is.factor(x))as.character(x)else(x));dput(df1)`

Comment: 'data.frame': 8 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ Farm      : Factor w/ 7 levels "Abel","Bollant",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 $ ID        : int  10000 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000
 $ Date      : Factor w/ 395 levels "1/1/2015","1/10/2015",..: 63 89 85 66 64 77 65 36
 $ Rum       : int  622 619 706 455 563 594 589 681
 $ Act       : int  438 484 466 449 471 546 449 424
 $ FDAT      : Factor w/ 304 levels "1/1/2015","1/10/2015",..: 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 46
 $ daystocalv: int  -10 -15 -12 -21 -19 -31 -20 9
 $ Prepartum : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0